# Как в Visual Studio 2017 просмотреть внутренние исключения?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Набросал вот такой тестовый пример:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        test(0,0);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw new Exception("ttt", e);
    }

}

static void test(int a,int b)
{
    var t=a / b;
}
```

Почему-то показывается только сообщение ttt

В предыдущей VS можно было вызвать модальное окно и изучить исключение.

Я знаю, что в VS 2017 модальное окно было заменено, однако, там должно отображаться внутреннее исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идее должно быть что-то такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно есть кнопка Details и стрелочками можно переключаться между исключениями.

Comment: вы же вроде совсем не новичок - неужели так трудно отформатировать код (ctrl+k выравнивает и влево тоже!), а не оставлять кривую лесенку в каждом вопросе?

Comment: @Андрей даже если и так, что в этом плохого? Кому-то ведь может и помочь впоследствии

Comment: Всегда через detais смотрел...

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, но в моем случае даже его не было=(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм... Нашел решение:

Если поставить `Enable native code debugging` в свойствах проекта, то все работает.

Однако, интересно, как сделать такое поведение по умолчанию для всех новых проектов.

---

Кажется понял, как это исправить не ставя галочку в `Enable native code debugging`.

Проблемы с исключениями возникают если стоит в настройках галочка в `use managed compatibility mode` .
Если ее убрать, то все работает как надо.

P.S Если кто-нибудь имеет более старую версию, то можно проверить, как эти галки влияют на отладку в старых VS и отписаться в комментах. Если это справедливо и для старых версий, то имеет смысл сделать вопрос общим для всех VS.